# Setting ng-show to true not working

Tags: angularjs

I have a `div` which shows whether the user is online or offline when the status changes.

```
<div ng-show="showStatus">
    Status:
    <div ng-show="online">You're online</div>
    <div ng-hide="online">You're offline</div>
</div>
```

Setting status on `$rootScope` variable:

```
    checkInternetApp.run(function ($window, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.online = navigator.onLine;
    $window.addEventListener("offline", function () {
        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
            $rootScope.online = false;
        });
    }, false);

    $window.addEventListener("online", function () {
        $rootScope.$apply(function () {
            $rootScope.online = true;
        });
    }, false);
});
```

Showing the `div` which contains `divs` showing online or offline:

```
    checkInternetApp.controller("checkInternetController", ["$scope", "$http", "$timeout", function ($scope, $http, $timeout) {
    $scope.showStatus = false;
    $scope.$watch("online", function () {

        $scope.showStatus = true; //set to true for 2 seconds
        $timeout(function () {
            $scope.showStatus = false; //hiding after 2 seconds
            console.log("timeout");
        }, 2000)
        console.log($scope.showStatus);
    })
    $scope.showDialog = function () {
        console.log($scope.showStatus);
    }
}])
```

But setting the `showStatus` to true and setting it to false again in  the controller is not working. I don't see the `div` containing the 2 `divs`. Setting `<div ng-show = "true">` works but `<div ng-show = "showStatus">` doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't use `$rootScope`. If you refresh your browser, then the scope values are clear . I'll suggest you need go with `$service` or `$broadcast`

Comment: @lin. hi I figured it out. `showStatus` was outside `ng-controller`. sorry i couldn't reply earlier..

Comment: Nice to hear you solved it. Would it ok for you to mark an answer as right?

Comment: @lin i would mark it as right, but it works even with `$scope.$watch("online")`. if that's not supposed to work i will mark an answer as right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some simple mistakes in your code. While you using `$scope.showStatus` and `$rootScope.online` your code should be like this:

#### Watch $rootScope

.... instead of $scope while `$rootScope.online` is an $rootScope param.

```
$rootScope.$watch("online", function (newValue, oldValue) {
    if (newValue) {
      $scope.showStatus = true; //set to true for 2 seconds
      $timeout(function () {
          $scope.showStatus = false; //hiding after 2 seconds
          $rootScope.online = false;
      }, 2000)
    }
});
```

#### View

Access `$rootScope` params in view with `$root.<objectName>`:

```
<div ng-show="showStatus">
    Status:
    <div ng-show="$root.online">You're online</div>
    <div ng-hide="$root.online">You're offline</div>
</div>
```

**--> [Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wj7dfzks/)**

Comment: t's working when i attach `showStatus` to `$rootScope` and also works when i `$scope.$watch("online'')` instead of `$rootScope.$watch("online")`

Comment: @Abhi it's hard to fix your problem if you don't show the essential parts of code. I added a working demo fiddle in my answer. As you can see, this solution works as expected. -> http://jsfiddle.net/wj7dfzks/ please compare your codes with this solution or add a fiddle to your question to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should change `$scope.$watch` to `$rootScope.$watch`, because of the `online` object is a rootScope object.

*I guess the problem is you have using  `$scope.showStatus = false;` within 2 seconds. So the div won't show. just remove the  `$scope.showStatus = false;` line from $timeout function and check.*

**Also you should follow which I have mentioned you in the comment under your question.**

> Don't use $rootScope. If you refresh your browser, then the scope values are clear . I'll suggest you need go with $service or  $Broadcast

And in my guess, you don't need to use $timeout, You may need this below logic.

```
$rootScope.$watch("online", function (oldValue,newValue) {  
       $scope.showStatus = false; 
        $scope.IsOnline= newValue;  
       if(newValue)
        $scope.showStatus = true; 

        console.log($scope.showStatus);
    })
    $scope.showDialog = function () {
        console.log($scope.showStatus);
    }
```

and the HTML

```
<div ng-show="showStatus">
    Status:
    <div ng-show="IsOnline">You're online</div>
    <div ng-hide="IsOnline">You're offline</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `I guess the problem is you have using  $scope.showStatus = false; within 2 seconds. So the div won't show. just remove the  $scope.showStatus = false; line from $timeout function and check.`. The user want to hide the status after 2 seconds. So its fine.

Comment: @lin  Am saying about if the OP calling the `$scope.showDialog()` function after that 2 seconds.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand you.

Comment: it's working when i attach `showStatus` to `$rootScope` and also works when i `$scope.$watch("online'')` instead of  `$rootScope.$watch("online")`